# How to overriding model controller with another controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes

Question:

Why the route still looking for `properties/create` and how to make it route to `admin_panels/properties#create`?

Explaination:

I'm creating my own admin panel from scratch. The main reason of creating the admin panel is to allow users easily perform `new`, `edit`, `update`, `create` and `destroy` actions for `property` model. So, I've created a new `PropertiesController` for `admin panel` to override the existing one.

What I'm expecting from this is after the `user` create a new `property`, it will create the property using the `admin_panels/properties#create`. However, what i get is it try to find a route to `properties/create` which is not correct.

New `AdminPanels::PropertiesController`

```
class AdminPanels::PropertiesController < PropertiesController
  before_action :set_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @properties = Property.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @property = Property.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.save
        format.html { redirect_to ADMIN_PANEL_PROPERTY_SHOW }
      else
        format.html { render ADMIN_PANEL_PROPERTY_NEW }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.update(property_params)
        format.html { redirect_to ADMIN_PANEL_PROPERTY_SHOW }
      else
        format.html { render ADMIN_PANEL_PROPERTY_EDIT }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @property.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to ADMIN_PANEL_PROPERTY_INDEX }
    end
  end

  private
  def set_property
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])
  end

  def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:name, :description, :address)
  end
end
```

to override existing `PropertiesController`

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_property, only: [:show]

  def index
    @properties = Property.all
  end

  def show
  end

  private
  def set_property
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])
  end

  def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:name, :description, :address)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users
resources :properties, only: [:index, :show]
namespace :admin_panels do
  resources :properties
end
```

Updated:

views > admin_panels > create > _form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for(@property) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :description
    = f.input :address

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have routes of `properties` for `index` and `show` and under `admin_panels` you have routes of all actions of `properties`

Change your routing file like this:

```
resources :users
namespace :admin_panels do
  resources :properties, only: [:index, :show]
end
```

Write the following command in terminal to view you routes.

```
rake routes
```

Write the following command in terminal to view routes of `admin_panels`

```
rake routes | grep admin_panel
```

Specify action and controller in form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @course_group, 
                    url: url_for(
                                 action: 'create',
                                 controller: 'admin_panels/properties'
                                ),
                    method: :post do |f| %>
```

Syntax might be different a little bit.

Comment: this is not the thing. If i'm doing this, I'll just have path for `admin_panels/properties/index` and `admin_panels/properties/show/:id`. However, i want the admin_panels/properties to be able to handle everything, whereas properties can only have `index` and `show` action. Do you ahve any solution for that?

Comment: In that case, where you are submitting your form, specify the particular path where you want to go.

Comment: i've updated my question. Currently, it redirect to `[POST] /properties` (which is not exist) instead of `[POST] /admin_panels/properties`. But why it still want to use `post create` from propeties_controller rather than admin_panels::properties_controller

Answer (score 0):

You can try that in two ways, first using the normal `url` and also by using the `url_for` helper of the simple_form_for.

Normal way,

```
<%= simple_form_for @provider, :url => admin_panel_properties_create_path, :method => :post do |f|%>
```

Using  the helper,

```
<%= simple_form_for  @provider,  url: url_for( action: 'create',controller: 'admin_panels/properties'),  method: :post do |f| %>
```